# Cardinality violation

Tags: model

There is one specific product on our site that is throwing an error:

```
Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query
was: SELECT `cataloginventory_stock_item`.*, `p`.`type_id` FROM
`cataloginventory_stock_item`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `p` ON product_id=p.entity_id 
WHERE (`cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`='38493', '38494') 
AND (stock_id = :stock_id)
```

This fatal error is occuring from:

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($value['products']);
```

The product is a shoe that comes in different sizes and colours.
The error is getting thrown when listing out the sizes on the page.
`$value['products']` is an array of the different sizes (hence different product ids).

However the other colours of the same shoe don't throw an error. I am thinking it's some mismatch in the database but I don't know where to start to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:345:"SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s), query was: SELECT `cataloginventory_stock_item`.*, `p`.`type_id` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `p` ON product_id=p.entity_id WHERE (`cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`='38493', '38494') AND (stock_id = :stock_id)";i:1;s:7512:"#0 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#4 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#5 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Stock/Item.php(57): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php(193): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Item->loadByProductId(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item), Array)
#8 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/app/design/frontend/enterprise/ca/template/configurable/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml(59): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item->loadByProduct(Array)
#9 /usr/share/nginx/calatest/www.website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/usr/share/ngin...')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$value['products']` is an array and the query expects one single value.
Try something like this:

```
$stockItems = array();
foreach ($value['products'] as $productId) {
    $stockItems[$productId] = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
}
```

You should end up with and array of stock items.

if `$value['products']` is a string do

```
$values = explode(',', $values);
```

then loop throuth `$values` instead of `$value['products']`

Answer (score 0):

maybe try switching

```
(`cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`='38493', '38494')
```

to

```
(`cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`='38493' OR `cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`= '38494')
```

also on a side note, I think with the new SUPEE6788 patch, the use of ` becomes deprecated